# Please help me understand where these errors are coming from

Tags: pdftex

```
\noindent
If the positive integer $x$ is not a divisor of $m$, the terms of this new 
sum are zero except when $m$ $-$ $k$ = $m$ mod $x$, when we have $a_{m-k}(x)- 
a_{m-k-1}(x) = 1$. On the other hand if \testit{x} is a divisor of $x$, the 
only nonvanishing terms occurs for $m - k = x$, when we have $a_{m-k}(x)- 
a_{m-k-1}(x) = 0 - (x - 1) $. Hence the sum is $1-x$[$x$ divides $m$]. Libri 
obtained his complicated formula by a less direct method,
applying Newton’s identities to compute the sum of the mth powers of the 
roots of the equation $t^{x-1}+t^{x-2}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+1=0$.)
\newline``
```

and also in this part it gives me the same error.

```
\indent Some of Libri’s papers are still well remembered, but [32] and [33] 
are not. I found no mention of them in $Science\; Citation\; Index$, after 
searching through all years of that index available in our library (1955 to 
date). However, the paper [33] did produce several ripples in mathematical 
waters when it originally appeared, because it stirred up a controversy about 
whether $0^0$ is defined. Most mathematicians agreed that $0^0 = 1$, but 
Cauchy [5, page 70] had listed $0^0$ together with other expression like 
$0/0$ and $\infty -\infty$ in a table of undefined forms. Libri’s 
justification for the equation $0^0 = 1$ was far from convincing, and a 
commentator who signed his name simply y “S” rose tothe attack [45]. August 
M¨obius [36] defended Libri, by presenting his former professor’s reason for 
believing that $0^0 = 1$ (basically a proof that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} x^x 
= 1).$ M\"obiuss also went further and presented a supposed proof that 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} f(x)^{g(x)} = 1$ whenever $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} 
f(x) = {\space}$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} g(x) = 0.$ Of course “S” then asked 
[3] whether M\"obius knew about functions such as $f(x) = e^{-1/x} $ and $ 
g(x) = x.$ (And paper [36] was quietly omitted from the historical record 
when the collected works of M\"obius were ultimately published.) The debate 
stopped there, apparently with the conclusion that
$0^0$ should be undefined.
```

In the end i get the correct equations as the pdf is generated but it keeps on giving me the same errors for both of these instances. I am farily new to latex so i am not too sure of these errors. Thanks for any help! [image: Errors]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You seem to have some special characters in your code.

Comment: Please tell us how the macro `\testit` is defined. Is it maybe a typo and, in fact, be spelled `\textit`? And should `M¨obius` be replaced with `M\"obius`? Finally, is the `$` symbol in the `{\space}$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+}` out of place?

Comment: yea it is suppose to me \textit. Thanks you for the help.

Comment: There seems to be a logical problem with `if \textit{x} is a divisor of $x$`. Do fix it unless you want to confuse your readers...

Comment: note they will not generate errors but you should never need `\indent` or `\noindent` in latex and never need to do this `$m$ $-$ $k$ = $m$ mod $x$` which will completely destroy the math layout as each symbol is set in a separate math expression with a non-math word space in between.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As pointed out by @Mico, there is a `\testit` which probably should be a `\textit`. Actually, at the place you used this command, it should have been a `$x$` anyway, and there is a place in which `$` should be `\textit`: `\textit{Science Citation Index}`. In addition to fixing that, I had to remove several special characters after "Newton", "Libri" , the `¨` signs etc. to make your code compilable. Finally, I fixed `$m$ $-$ $k$ = $m$ mod $x$` to become `$m-k=m\mod x$`, which is why I load `amsmath`, and I replaced `\cdot\cdot\cdot` with `\cdots`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
If the positive integer $x$ is not a divisor of $m$, the terms of this new 
sum are zero except when $m-k=m\mod x$, when we have $a_{m-k}(x)- 
a_{m-k-1}(x) = 1$. On the other hand if $x$ is a divisor of $x$, the 
only nonvanishing terms occurs for $m - k = x$, when we have $a_{m-k}(x)- 
a_{m-k-1}(x) = 0 - (x - 1) $. Hence the sum is $1-x$ [$x$ divides $m$]. Libri 
obtained his complicated formula by a less direct method,
applying Newton's identities to compute the sum of the mth powers of the 
roots of the equation $t^{x-1}+t^{x-2}+\cdots+1=0$.


Some of Libri's papers are still well remembered, but [32] and [33] 
are not. I found no mention of them in \textit{Science Citation Index}, after 
searching through all years of that index available in our library (1955 to 
date). However, the paper [33] did produce several ripples in mathematical 
waters when it originally appeared, because it stirred up a controversy about 
whether $0^0$ is defined. Most mathematicians agreed that $0^0 = 1$, but 
Cauchy [5, page 70] had listed $0^0$ together with other expression like 
$0/0$ and $\infty -\infty$ in a table of undefined forms. Libri's 
justification for the equation $0^0 = 1$ was far from convincing, and a 
commentator who signed his name simply ``S'' rose tothe attack [45]. August 
M\"obius [36] defended Libri, by presenting his former professor's reason for 
believing that $0^0 = 1$ (basically a proof that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} x^x 
= 1).$ M\"obius also went further and presented a supposed proof that 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} f(x)^{g(x)} = 1$ whenever $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} 
f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} g(x) = 0.$ Of course``S'' then asked 
[3] whether M\"obius knew about functions such as $f(x) = e^{-1/x} $ and $ 
g(x) = x.$ (And paper [36] was quietly omitted from the historical record 
when the collected works of M\"obius were ultimately published.) The debate 
stopped there, apparently with the conclusion that
$0^0$ should be undefined.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope to have found most of the issues, and that you do not hardcode the reference numbers like `[44]` in your real document, but use `bibtex`, `biblatex`, `biber` or something similar instead.

Comment: @Mico Definitely. I was just about to submit this. And thanks a lot for the edit!

Comment: `mth` should probably be `$m$th` or `$m$\nobreakdash-th`